# Can't start elasticsearch an node slave

Tags: elasticsearch

I cant't start elasticsearch with node.master:false

elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: graylog2
node.name: "second"

node.master: false

node.data: true


index.number_of_shards: 2

bootstrap.mlockall: true


discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: 192.168.93.76

script.disable_dynamic: true
```

service elasticsearch restart

netstat -an | grep 9200

NULL

Comment: What is showing up in your cluster log?

Answer (score 0):

YML has very strict syntax, you need to add a space between `node.master` and `false`:

```
node.master: false
```

Comment: yes, i am undestand
but im sorry, in my config i have spase and error in the first message